# Windows 10 boot takes an extreme long time

Tags: windows-10, boot, performance, analysis

I'm having trouble fixing a slow Windows 10 boot.
The computer itself is pretty decent: core i5-6260U, 16GB RAM, 512GB SSD, Intel Iris 540. This all in a Intel NUC6i5SYH.

In the beginning, it booted within 10 seconds. 1 year later, it became more than a minute. Once the login screen of windows is visible, everything works instantly. It's only the loading of the OS (The period where you see the windows logo and and loader)

I've already formatted the HDD and reinstalled Windows, no difference.
I've already updated the BIOS to the latest version, no difference.

So now I'm doing a boot analysis, but I'm a bit stuck with how to get the correct analysis. These measurements all happen after the slow part.

[image]

How can I analyse what happens before this (The Windows loading screen)?

Comment: on the Picture it also takes 12s. in generic events, look for WinLogon events and look for time at Start/Stop opcode of the tasks to see which task takes so long

Comment: But those 12 seconds is me entering my password inclusive... It already loaded for more than a minute before the recording started

Comment: no, not according to the picture. Since Win8, the boot logo hides BIOS/UEFI init messages. maybe this takes very long.

Comment: No it does not, i see the loading screen of windows. I've enabled the bios/UEFI init messages and I've already tried to reset bios to defaults and updated it as well. But in any case, it loads for more than 100 seconds (after bios/UEFI messages) before showing the login screen.

Comment: capture some traces and load them in WPA, apply the profile until you see this delay.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this that came up after a Windows 10 upgrade. I ultimately fixed the problem by disabling the on-board NIC in BIOS. Seemed to be an interaction between the UEFI BIOS and the OS driver. Probably a BIOS or driver bug, but neither device had updates available. Disabling the device in the device manager also made the problem go away, but I disabled in BIOS to prevent it from accidentally being turned on.

Once replaced the balky device with a modern USB NIC, all problems went away.

If the delay is happening BEFORE the BIOS screen appears, it will be UEFI related. Try disabling different devices that interact with UEFI, rebuilding the UEFI partition, or updating BIOS, NIC drivers, etc.

In my case, after total removal of power, the device booted up instantly. After any shutdown, boot was delayed a long time, as long as the motherboard had power in between the boot attempts. This led me to believe that some state was being saved somewhere on the motherboard that made the UEFI unhappy.